# API not work on Third Level Domain

Tags: php, json, api, curl

i have some problems.

I need to keep data from coinmarketcap. When I was developing on localhost it worked well.
But on third level domain coinfollow.altervista.org i can not receive the data

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$outputdecoded = json_decode($output, true);
echo $outputdecoded;
```

I try in another domain mywebsite.com and it worked. I think that the problem is coinfollow.altervista.org domain.
I need to save coinmarketcap data into my database with a simple query.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Your domain name is highly unlikely to affect this - cURL is going to run server-to-server, all the other server's gonna see is your server's IP address. Dump the value of `$output` and see what's being returned.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run the site from coinfollow.altervista.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is a server config issue on coinfollow.altervista.org, such as curl not being enabled for php.

You can run `phpinfo();` to see if curl is installed.
If it is installed try running `echo curl_error($ch)` to see if there are any errors returning from curl

Comment: error: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: This might be a proxy configuration issue on your server. Is this your server and are you able to configure the system / do you have root or sudo access?

Comment: Solve! I add altervista in proxy whitelist, thank you so much for help